# Non-capitalized constant names in Ruby

Tags: ruby, emoji

So, there's a jokey repo called [active_emoji](https://github.com/sferik/active_emoji), which basically adds a load of emoji aliases to Ruby methods.

It also includes this:

```
 = Numeric

class 
  alias  step
end
```

However, when trying to write some specs for the repo, it fails with

```
active_emoji/lib/active_emoji/core_ext/numeric.rb:3: class/module name must be CONSTANT (SyntaxError)
```

Is there a way of forcing the emoji to be recognized as being a constant? I'm assuming this error is because Ruby sees that the  emoji symbol isn't capitalized...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is actually due to:

```
class
```

The first line, which assigns `Numeric` to a variable, works fine in IRB. So does aliasing the `step` method. But Ruby will only accept `class [ConstantName]` as valid -- you can't use a variable here.

Comment: So is there no way to change that, except to patch the Ruby Class class itself?

Comment: @PeterSouter: yes, no way to change that. It's basically hard-coded in the parser.